# c# How can I update a label within a form from another class that has a void method?

Tags: c#, user-interface, events, udp

Right now, I have a form with a label, lblHeartBeat. I have a UDP listener that takes in data with the value for lblHeartBeat. I'm wondering, how can I change the label in realtime with my UDP client from another class?

Right now I have

```
private void btnBopIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name;
    name=txtName.Text;
    UDPListener myListener=new UDPListener();
    myListener.GetData(name);
}
```

and the section of my class with the UDP client is:

```
public class UDPListener
{
public void GetData(string Name)
...
while (!done)
{
    byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
    var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    var data = result.Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Trim().Split('='))
        .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);

    string myFunString = result.ToString();

    if (myFunString.Contains(Name) == true && myFunString.Contains("Heartbeat"))
    {
       decimal value=data["Hearbeat"] 
       //I'd like to have it some way below that:
       form1.lblHeartbeat=value;
    }
}
```

Mind you that my UDPlistener is a void method. I figure having it decimal will only return one value to the form, and not autoupdate. Should I try to create an event within the if statement so that it changes the label? Cheers

Update: I should also note that my UDP Listener takes on the string from txtName.Text. I may have to run this asynchronously.
Update2: Finally got it to work. In addition to Rob's answer, I had to invoke it as I made my UDPlistiner operate on a different thread

Comment: it is singlethread or multiple?

Comment: it is multiple. I'm thinking if I need to call the UDP listener asynchrously for that reason.

Comment: and you want to update only label through this form? is it right?

Comment: I only have one form. Once I click the button, I would like the label to update itself automatically from then on as I have run my UDPlistener. Please let me know if I need to clarify something.

Comment: Rexamining it, I think this is a threading issue. I need to set my name as an object for starters...

Comment: Yeah, when we used any control t Thread we need to make `threadStarter` for that control. it then automatically update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
UDPListener myListener=new UDPListener();
```

You should either pass the form, or the particular label you're interested in. Then your `UDPListener` would be able to reference the form and its controls. For example:

```
private void btnBopIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UDPListener myListener = new UDPListener(this);
}
```

```
public class UDPListener 
{
    private Form1 _form { get; set; }
    public UDPListener (Form1 form) //Assuming your form class is `Form1`
    {
        _form = form;
    }

    //..

}
```

Then you can write this:

```
_form.lblHeartbeat.Text = value;
```

Assuming you declare your label as *public*

Comment: Thanks, but I was under the impression that the label can only be declared within the UI, not in another class...

Comment: @DamienScott The label stays the same. You simply mark it as public, not private. It's configurable in the UI designer, possibly under something like 'access modifier'. The only thing changing here is `UDPListener` and `btnBopIt_Click`

Comment: Thanks. In addition, I also needed to invoke the method, as my UDPListener was on a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest slightly different approach.

Define an `EventHandler` in `UDPListener` and subscribe to that event in your main form.

```
public class UDPListener
{
     public event Action<string> MessageReceived;

     ...         
}
```

In your (`while`)loop modify your code to notify to listeners.

```
 if (myFunString.Contains(Name) == true && myFunString.Contains("Heartbeat"))
 {
      decimal value=data["Hearbeat"] 
      //I'd like to have it some way below that:
      if(MessageReceived != null) MessageReceived(value); 
 }
```

Final step, subscribing to this event in `Form1`

```
private void btnBopIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     UDPListener myListener=new UDPListener();
     myListener.MessageReceived += (s) => lblHeartbeat.Text = s;
}
```

Comment: Why did you need that? you could add `Thread.Sleep(2000)` but I seriously doubted its need.

Comment: I'm assuming that if the event occurs, it will get raised in the btn Event, even if it has finished running? I think I have to go through my code to see why I'm unable to have the event raised..

Comment: I would suggest either move this code from button event or declare the global variable (`UDPListener myListener`)

Comment: Hmm, I may need to find an alternative to the button event. I declared UDPListiner myListener as public. I do now get the event raised, but get the common error "lblHeartbeat" accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on, which I don't understand as isn't it raised in right thread..?